# Pass data from presented View in Navigation Controller, back to custom view (XIB)

Tags: arrays, swift, database, xcode, xib

Im using a custom XIB file as a popover for a view controller. The XIB file contains two buttons = "send" and "add additional fields". Selecting the button to add additional fields presents another view controller that's embedded in a Navigation controller. When the user lands on that controllers screen, and selects their extra options, that data should be passed back to the XIB's `var extraOptions = [String]()` field. From there, the user should be able to upload their post by selecting "send".

The problem Im having is **data is not being passed back to the XIB from the view controller embedded in the navigation controller**.

Is this even possible? I've tried every solution I could think of: protocol/delegate method, setting the `var extraOptions` field in the XIB file, from the presented controller before dismissing it and returning back to the XIB, and this is my latest attempt:

Custom XIB named **CreatePostModal**(view controller thats a pop over)

```
@objc func addExtraOptions(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExtraOptionsNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**ExtraOptionsViewController**

```
@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let navController = presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
        let presenter = navController.topViewController as! CreatePostModal
        presenter.extraOptions = self.extraOptionsSelected
        print("These are the options selected ==> \(present.extraOptions)") //this prints the options and shows that they're there, but the array is empty whenever a user tries to upload the data
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see, in the print method, it prints the variable and shows that the data is there, but when returning the XIB file, and the user saves & uploads the data, the field is showing up as empty.

**How do I pass data back to a XIB from a view embedded in a navigation controller?**

Comment: Use the notification.

Comment: the navigation controller would need to inject a deleagte into the VC if you want to use delegates, which would require a custom nav controller.  Then the data could be passed back down the delegate chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one in three ways:

- NSNotificationCenter
- Delegate
- Closure